# weird py2exe error

Tags: python, py2exe

I made this code into an executable with py2exe:

```
# File: zipfile-example-1.py
from Tkinter import *
import zipfile
import os
import glob
Admin = Tk()
Admin.configure(bg='grey')
La = Label(Admin,bg='grey', text='Dir to back up.')
La.pack()
Ent = Entry(Admin, bg='grey')
Ent.pack()
la = Label(Admin,bg='grey', text='Zip file name.')
la.pack()
ent = Entry(Admin,bg='grey')
ent.pack()

def zipdir():
    fi = ent.get()
    fii = fi+'.zip'
    pl = Ent.get()
    pll = pl+'/*' 
    file = zipfile.ZipFile(fii, "w")

    # list filenames
    for name in glob.glob(pll):
        print name
        file.write(name,os.path.basename(name),zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)

    file.close()
    file = zipfile.ZipFile(fii, "r")
    for info in file.infolist():
        print info.filename, info.date_time, info.file_size, info.compress_size

Bu = Button(Admin,text='Backup.',command=zipdir)
Bu.pack(side=RIGHT)
Admin.mainloop()
```

When I run it I get this in the console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "zip.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "zipfile.pyc", line 462, in <module>
  File "zipfile.pyc", line 474, in ZipExtFile
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'compile'
```

Im pretty sure its source code from my other music downloading program.
I've already tried to reinstall Python, reinstall py2exe and scanned for viruses.

I'm using Win 64 Python 2.7.1 Windows 7.

Does anyone know why I get this error?

Never mind i ran it again after compiling it into a exe again and it worked odly enough.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the only relevant part of this error message is `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'compile'`

Comment: There are horrendous things on your code, like the two widgets `Ent` and `ent`. You should check that. Anyway it seems that  `print name` is not printing a list of files, but the contents of something. Could you please simplify the code just to the point it doesn't behave correctly? As you have two prints now is confusing. Ah! I tried the code and unlike you I got a list of files printed. Check also your input!.

Comment: No, its not the code its only when i run the exe i get the error mesage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have dashes in the name of a Python module.  And you can't call a Python module `zipfile`, because there's already a [standard library module](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html) with that name.  Does it work if you rename it to `z.py`, before you run `py2exe`?